# How to replace onclicklistener with a holder?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm doing a robot, and I've found a code that would help me, but it has clickers and I want holders, can you help me to replace them?

I mean, It's a robot car, in my app I only can do short taps, but I want a long tap.

Help me please!

This is the code of one of those:

```
btnUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btnUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      up();
    }
  });

private void up() {
  if (btSocket != null) {
    try {

      btSocket.getOutputStream().write("d".toString().getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      msg("Error");
    }
  }
}
```

[[image: dgfhg[1]]

Comment: "i want holders" what do you mean by that? your question is not clear.

Comment: i wanna do long taps, not only shorts

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: @Armand09 can you pleasae reframe the question so that people can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with help of onTouchListener and detect when user put his finger on the button and start pressing it and when lift his finger from that and stop holding that button.

```
btnUp.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        //start pressing
                        //user start putting down button
                        //start doing what you want
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        //end pressing
                        //user stop pressing the button and lift his finger
                        //stop doing what you were
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To do long taps(Long click), you have to hold the button for little long time, and you should use setOnLongCLickListener instead of setOnClickListener. Hope this helps.

```
 btnUp.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

            up();
            return false;
        }
    });
```